# Composite Control event is not triggering

Tags: javascript, sapui5

i have a control as below

i need to fire the event closed when i click on the close icon press

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/Control",
           "sap/m/Carousel",
           "sap/m/Panel",
           "sap/m/Toolbar",
           "sap/ui/core/Icon",
           "sap/m/Label",
           "sap/m/Button",
           "sap/m/ToolbarSpacer"], function (Control,Carousel,Panel,Toolbar,Icon,Label,Button,ToolbarSpacer) {
"use strict";
return Control.extend("com.example.Control", {
    metadata : {

        aggregations : {

            _panel : {
                 type : "sap.m.Panel",
                 multiple: false,
                 visibility:'hiddden'
            }            
        },
        events : {
            closed : {

            }
        }
    },
    renderer  : function (oRM, oControl) {
        oRM.write("<div");
        oRM.writeControlData(oControl);
        oRM.addClass("sapUiSizeCompact");
        oRM.writeClasses();
        oRM.write(">");
        oRM.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation("_panel"));
        oRM.write("</div>");
    },
    init : function () {
        var that = this;
        var _carousel = new Carousel({
            pages : [new Label({
                text : "Test"
            }),
            new Label({
                text : "Test"
            })]
        });
        var _closeIcon = new Icon({
            src : "sap-icon://decline",
            press :jQuery.proxy(this.onCloseInfoWindow,this)
        });
        var _toolBar = new Toolbar({
            content : [
                       new Label({
                           text :"Information"
                       }),
                       new ToolbarSpacer(),
                       _closeIcon,
                     ]
        });
        var _panel = new Panel({
            headerToolbar : _toolBar
        });
        _panel.addContent(_carousel);
        this.setAggregation('_panel',_panel);
    },

    onCloseInfoWindow : function(oEvent){

    }
});
});
```

The onCloseInfoWindow is not triggering the press event when click on close icon

do i need to do some add the icon also as aggregation and need to render?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `press :jQuery.proxy(this.onCloseInfoWindow,this)` ? I've never used that jQuery.proxy in ui5. 
For triggering the close function, you could do

```
var _closeIcon = new Icon({
        src : "sap-icon://decline",
        press : function(oEvent){
             this.fireClosed(oEvent);
        }.bind(this)
    });
```

Comment: In the press function this is in icon context not in control context so we need to use proxy

Comment: @chiranjeevigk the bind at the end of the function change the scope of this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to fire the `closed` event that you have created in your custom control ?

Use the below code for calling the closed event from your **custom control**:

```
onCloseInfoWindow : function(oEvent){
        //console.log('Called');
        this.fireClosed(oEvent);
    }
```

**View XML**: here, Control is my name for your control.

```
<c:Control closed='onClose'/>
```

**Controller**:

```
onClose:function(oEvent) {
        console.log('Closed Called!');
    }
```

Comment: Yes but onCloseInfoWindow is not calling

Comment: Your code is calling onCloseInfoWindow. I made no changes to your code. May be you can try a different version of UI5 so jQuery version is different, which might be causing the issue. Also, are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: now i came to know the issue, their is not issue in Custom control which i have written, problem is adding this to openlayer3 overlay https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overlay.html where i ave given the element as custom control id, thats why its not working